# About the relationship between view and controller in MVC paradigm, specifically Sencha Touch,

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to use Sencha Touch 2 to write an app to help me memorize all those vocabulary.

I'm working on the part that a list displays some words. I want the list view to be able to consult the notebook controller so that it can know whether each word is in the notebook already and that way it can display an 'add to notebook' or 'remove from notebook' button for each word accordingly.

I'm just wondering whether it's a good practice to let view initiate requests to controller. When working in Objective-C, it seems that I can have this done by setting a controller to be the delegate of a view. So is there an equivalent approach in Sencha Touch?

Comment: In Touch / ExtJS, controllers should only handle events on a view. Use them only as assistants to a view...a place to move event handlers to.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Well, then could you please give me some advice about this particular scenario I describe? Should I pass the information of whether it's in the notebook along in the store? Thanks very much!

Comment: I find it's best to start by trying with the code in the view, and then moving it to a controller (just when you are starting out)

Answer (score 0):

The Sencha MVC is just a guideline, and the structure is not strictly enforced. For example, you can create an app with no controllers by putting all the event listeners in the views. Or, you can just maintain 1 controller file that handles all your views. It's up to you.

It sounds like you are trying to check whether the contents of the ListStore has values that are already in the Notebook store. What I would do is create a "fake" column in the ListStore that checks its values against the Notebook store.

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.ListStore', {
   ...
   fields: [
      ... (other fields) ...
      {
         name: 'isInNotebook',
         convert: function(value, record) {
            return this.verifyInNotebook(record.get('fieldToVerify'));
         }
      }
   ],
   verifyInNotebook: function(verifyValue) {
       var notestore = Ext.getStore('NotebookStore');
       return notestore.FindExact(verifyValue);
   }
}
```

Then in your view, you would decide which button to show depending on the value of the column 'isInNotebook', which is a virtual generated column.

I hope this helps.